# ListBox OnSelectionChanged event stops working with "many" items

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox

I noticed a very strange behavior: 
in my windows phone 7 I have a ListBox that can contain anything from 1-2 to 2-300 items.
I noticed that when the number of items is big (not sure about the number but for sure >150 items) the OnSelectionChanged event is not raised.

This is the XAML of my listbox

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Posts}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource IconsWithText}"
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility ="Disabled"
        SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged" >
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

And the template for the ItemTemplate is:

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="IconsWithText">
    <Grid x:Name="ThumLink"  Width="160" Height="140" Margin="10" Background="#FF666666">
        <Image Source="Resources/Images/All.png" Visibility="{Binding Path=VisibilityAll}" />
        <Image delay:LowProfileImageLoader.UriSource="{Binding Picture}"
                Visibility="{Binding Path=VisibilityPic}"
                Stretch="UniformToFill" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
        <Border x:Name="border" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="#d9ffffff" Height="62" BorderBrush="Black" Visibility="{Binding Path=VisibilityPic}"  >
            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Text="{Binding Title}" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxHeight="60" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSmallStyle}"
                Foreground="Black" FontSize="20" Margin="4,1,4,0" Height="62"/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Is this a bug or did I do something wrong? I was in debug and the event handler never gets called, but it works when the items are not many.

Simone

Comment: You might want to show us the `ListBox` xaml.  Would you for example be suppling a `StackPanel` in its `ItemPanelTemplate` because that would fail with so many items.

Comment: Added the code... yes, using a StackPanel... why is it failing? Bug? Any workaround?

Comment: Would using a virtualizingstackpanel do any better?

Comment: Can you also provide the item template you are using?  (BTW preceed your answer comment with @anthonywjones:  The SO notification system understands this convention).

Comment: What happens if you take out both of the images from the item template, does it still fail?  If not add the "all" image back does that still fail?  If not remove the "all" image and restore the other image, does it fail now?

Comment: It seems like adding VirtualisingStackPanel with  VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with using the plain `StackPanel` is that all visual object will be created and added to the `StackPanel` which will be very expensive in terms of memory and may trip over other limits in the rendering system.

Try changing to:-

```
<VirtualisingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
```

So far though I've not been able to reproduce your problem with 300 items even using a plain StackPanel.

Comment: Also had to add  VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" in the ListBox to make it work with my long list of objects (now it grew to 400+ items)